# Is the yolk of the egg should not be eaten for bodybuilding?

Tags: nutrition, body-building

My friend have suggested that a boiled egg is great rather than fried omelet but yolk should not be consumed as it makes fat.

Comment: If you're bodybuilding properly then "making fat" isn't a concern for you. I think you'd get better guidance in the Fitness stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common myth that egg yolk should not be eaten for bodybuilding. Unfortunately, it is a misguided thing.

- Egg yolk contains vitamins and minerals in varying amount.
- It raises good cholesterol. Cholesterol promotes more muscle growth. A study showed that those with higher cholesterol levels built more muscle than those will lower levels.
- Egg yolks are a fantastic food source. This goes for everyone, but especially for the bodybuilder.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). We require that all answers are backed up with reliable references, since they are the only way for the community to assess the merit of an answer regardless of the reader's background. You can always [edit] your answer to add some. For more information on site policies, please take our [tour] or visit the [help] and [meta]. Thanks!

Comment: Plus, the yolk contains about  50% of the protien of an egg!